# Why does my recursive setTimeout with a delay as the difference between now and future time run a bit too early?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datetime, settimeout

I'm checking if the US stock market is open at 3 different times (9:30AM, 1:00PM, 4:00PM EST).

Basically, I check when the next market event time is, then I get the difference in milliseconds and set that as the setTimeout delay. Once the setTimeout callback runs, I do the same thing again (if client's current time has passed all market event times, then I move all market event times forward another 24 hours and do the whole process again).

However, I noticed the callback always runs ever so slightly ahead of time, which results in fetching the data too early (for example, fetching the market status at 4:00PM EST should return { isMarketOpen: false }, but since it's a second or two too early, it returns { isMarketOpen: true } ). It works if I change all event times by adding a few seconds to each like this:

```
const getMarketTimes = (est: Date): MarketTimes => {
  const d = `${est.getFullYear()}-${est.getMonth() + 1}-${est.getDate()}`
  return {
    open: zonedTimeToUtc(`${d} 09:30:03`, timeZone).getTime(),
    earlyClose: zonedTimeToUtc(`${d} 13:00:03`, timeZone).getTime(),
    close: zonedTimeToUtc(`${d} 16:00:03`, timeZone).getTime(),
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm aware that setTimeout execution times are not too reliable, but I'm assuming it shouldn't be off by more that 250-500ms? Could it possibly be a browser number rounding issue? My last resort would be to do this on my server using a cron job with SSE, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { zonedTimeToUtc, utcToZonedTime } from 'date-fns-tz'
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material'

import { light, dark } from '../theme'
import App from './App'

const timeZone = 'America/New_York'

type MarketTimes = {
  open: number
  earlyClose: number
  close: number
}

/* Market event times */
const getMarketTimes = (est: Date): MarketTimes => {
  const d = `${est.getFullYear()}-${est.getMonth() + 1}-${est.getDate()}`
  return {
    open: zonedTimeToUtc(`${d} 09:30:00`, timeZone).getTime(),
    earlyClose: zonedTimeToUtc(`${d} 13:00:00`, timeZone).getTime(),
    close: zonedTimeToUtc(`${d} 16:00:00`, timeZone).getTime(),
  }
}

type GlobalState = {
  initialLoading: boolean
  isMarketOpen?: boolean
}

export default () => {
  const [{ initialLoading, isMarketOpen }, setGlobalState] = React.useState<GlobalState>({
    initialLoading: true,
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isMarketOpen !== undefined) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setGlobalState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          initialLoading: false,
        }))
      }, 5000)
    }
  }, [isMarketOpen])

  const { refetch } = useQuery('/market-status', {
    enabled: false,
    retry: 3,
    cacheTime: 0,
    onSuccess: (response: AxiosResponse<{ isMarketOpen: boolean }>) => {
      setGlobalState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isMarketOpen: response.data.isMarketOpen,
      }))
    },
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refetch()
  }, [])

  /* Recursively check if US stock market is open at:
  9:30AM, 1:00PM (early close on holidays), and 4:00PM EST */
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const est = utcToZonedTime(new Date(), timeZone)
    let marketTimes = getMarketTimes(est)

    const msUntilNextEvent = (): number => {
      const now = new Date().getTime()

      if (now < marketTimes.open) {
        return marketTimes.open - now
      }

      if (now < marketTimes.earlyClose) {
        return marketTimes.earlyClose - now
      }

      if (now < marketTimes.close) {
        return marketTimes.close - now
      }

      est.setHours(est.getHours() + 24)
      marketTimes = getMarketTimes(est)
      return marketTimes.open - now
    }

    let timeoutID: any

    const fetch = () => {
      refetch()
      timeoutID = setTimeout(fetch, msUntilNextEvent())
    }

    timeoutID = setTimeout(fetch, msUntilNextEvent())

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    }
  }, [])

  const theme = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (initialLoading) {
      return dark
    }

    return isMarketOpen ? light : dark
  }, [initialLoading, isMarketOpen])

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <App isLoading={initialLoading} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's just an educated guess, but `const now = new Date().getTime()` uses your system time. I guess your whole system might be running a second (or even a fraction) ahead of the stock markets clock (which will be most likely more accurate)

Comment: Adding to your initial thoughts, `setTimeout` is pretty accurate except when any other task is blocking JavaScripts event loop.

Comment: @WolverinDEV Thanks for the feedback. I created a test route on my Node server that fakes open/close times and the same thing happened. So, the issue still persists even when I'm not using the market api.

Comment: Had you tried adding the current client timestamp as payload to the server and check it against the server time? I still think this is more a clock sync issue rather than anything else.

Comment: @WolverinDEV I have not, I'll try that.

Comment: Highly depending on your needs, but if you actually need to do stuff exactly when the market opens, I would not use the clients PC clock as a reference. You may try to initiating your own reference point. (PS: `Date.getTime` might also be [artificially reduced in precision to prevent timing and fingerprinting attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#reduced_time_precision))

Comment: @WolverinDEV I see. Yeah, that seems to be the more reliable way of going about it. Thanks.

Comment: I would change the logic so that when the function runs, it uses the current time to set market open/closed and set itself to run at the next event time. That way if it runs a few seconds early it just sets things to their current values and itself to run in a few seconds time.